# How to make Jenkins build using one set of nuget URLs (Artifactory proxy) but build locally using another (original)?

Tags: github, jenkins, nuget, artifactory

So the DevOps want me to use Artifactory nuget proxies for my nugets in .NET solution in VS 2022. Jenkins is using them for the build.

However I find this setup extremely flaky (Artifactory often fails to deliver and sometime there hours of outage and I am not sure what would happen when new nuget version will be available for public but not in our Artifactory, so please skip "why").

What I want is to have been able to use different `package.config` in my VS 2022 from the one Jenkins uses.

Everything is automated through github enterprise.

Whats the best way to achieve this?